# Python Selenium, select the next element in html DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

i have to make some automation on a page.
The page consists of table where inside each **td** element i have 2 **a** tags, the first one with a class, the second one has no class or id.

i can easily select the one with the class, but how to get the other one? is there a way to select the element next to another one like in css?

this is a draft of the structure of the page

```
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <a class="mylink"> element 1 </a>
            <a>
                <img src="">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <a class="mylink"> element 2 </a>
            <a>
                <img src="">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can select the first one with

```
fileLinkClass = "mylink"
driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=fileLinkClass)
```

but i need to select and click the a link without the class. How can i accomplish this?
Thank you so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using css selector

For single element selection

```
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.mylink + a')
```

For multiple elements selection

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.mylink + a')
```

Make a list slicing then click. For example:

```
element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.mylink + a')
element = element[0].clik()
element = element[1].clik()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath selector

```
'//td/a[2]'
```

to find all second 'a's under a 'td'